# Data-Tier application - manual table alter

Tags: sql-server, data-tier-applications

Let's say I registered my Data-Tier Application into SQL Server 2014. Is there a way how can I disable manual altering of tables? So I can force developers to publish new version of data-tier application instead of manual altering any table in the database ?

How the data-tier application changes when I alter something manually bypassing data-tier upgrade ?

The point of my question is:
Someone can add a column directly to the table for a customer bypassing a data-tier upgrade. That means our project in visual studio will be outdated. I would like to force anyone to change a database only though data-tier upgrade.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this with Ssdt, the best you can do is to stop future deployments by detecting drift.

Redgate have a product (free version available) that does this it is called dlm dashboard and notifies and allows you to block changes unless they have been pre-approved etc:

https://www.red-gate.com/products/dlm/dlm-dashboard/

Ed

Comment: it's a pity as someone can change my tables in SSMS even it's registered data-tier. Someone can add a new column for a customer directly instead thought data-tier upgrade.